# Custom ListView Add Data from Sql

Tags: android, xamarin

Hello i have create a custom listview. Now i want to add data from sql in each of my items. My original code in mainactivity is this:

```
mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);
mItems = new List<Person>();
mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Dim", LastName = "Chris", Age = "25", Gender = "Male" });

MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);
mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
```

Now I want to add in each of my items data from sql.I try something like this:

```
mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);


SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,LastName,Age,Gender FROM Members", con);
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlReader.Read())
{     


mItems = new List<Person>();
mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(), LastName = sqlReader["LastName"].ToString(), Age = sqlReader["Age"].ToString(), Gender = sqlReader["Gender"].ToString() });

MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);
mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
}
sqlReader.Close();
```

I can see only my last Sql row. But i want see all my sql rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an instance of `MyListViewAdapter` for *each* row from the query. Each `ListView` only needs a single instance of Adapter.

So, replace this

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{     
    mItems = new List<Person>();
    mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(), LastName = sqlReader["LastName"].ToString(), Age = sqlReader["Age"].ToString(), Gender = sqlReader["Gender"].ToString() });

    MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);
    mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

with

```
// List of persons
mItems = new List<Person>();

// Add persons from the query to our list
while (sqlReader.Read())
{     
    mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = sqlReader["Name"].ToString(), LastName = sqlReader["LastName"].ToString(), Age = sqlReader["Age"].ToString(), Gender = sqlReader["Gender"].ToString() });
}

// Create an adapter for this list
MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);

// Bind the ListView to this adapter
mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: Thank you it Works!